# Drawing a Shape to a Window Using C translated into ARM instructions

Tags: c, gcc, arm, drawing, qemu

I am currently trying to learn the ways of C and am using GCC to translate C to ARM instructions. To do so, I am attempting to draw a simple shape to the window, but am having a hard time working out how to do it without using a graphics package like . Here is what I have managed to work out so far:

My make file is pretty self-explanatory I would say.

```
CC=/cygdrive/c/Users/Ribbyon/Desktop/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_3-2016q1-20160330-win32/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc
LD=/cygdrive/c/Users/Ribbyon/Desktop/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_3-2016q1-20160330-win32/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld.exe
AS=$(CC)
OBJCOPY=/cygdrive/c/Users/Ribbyon/Desktop/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_3-2016q1-20160330-win32/bin/arm-none-eabi-objcopy.exe
QEMU=/cygdrive/c/Users/Ribbyon/Desktop/qemu/qemu-system-arm.exe

#these should be cross-platform...
CC+= -Wall -c -mcpu=arm926ej-s -marm -Werror
LD+=-Map kernelmap.txt -T linkerscript.txt
AS+= -c -x assembler-with-cpp -mcpu=arm926ej-s
QEMUARGS=-machine integratorcp -kernel kernel.bin -serial stdio
DISPLAY?=:0
export DISPLAY
SDL_STDIO_REDIRECT=no
export SDL_STDIO_REDIRECT

all: 
    $(AS) kernelasm.s
    $(CC) kernelc.c
    $(CC) console.c
    $(LD) -o kernel.tmp kernelasm.o kernelc.o console.o
    $(OBJCOPY) -Obinary kernel.tmp kernel.bin
    $(QEMU) $(QEMUARGS) kernel.bin


clean:
    -/bin/rm *.o *.exe *.bin *.img *.tmp
```

Linkerscript to put it together:

```
ENTRY (_start)

SECTIONS {

    /* The kernel will be loaded at this address in RAM.
            The dot (.) means "the current location" */
    . = 0x10000 ;

    .text : {

        /* stext = start of text (read-only) section */
        stext = .;

        /* .text = program code. rodata and rdata = read-only data */
        *(.text) 
        *(.rodata)
        *(.rdata)
        *(.rdata$zzz)

        /* etext = end of text section */ 
        etext = .;

        /* pad to a 4K boundary */
        . = ALIGN( ABSOLUTE(.) , 0x1000 );

        /* start of data (writable) section */
        _sdata = .;
        sdata = .;

        *(.data) 

        _edata = .;
        edata = .;
        /* end of data section */

        /* bss: Block Started by Symbol: Uninitialized data */
        _sbss = . ; 
        sbss = . ;

        *(COMMON) 
        *(.bss)  

        _ebss = . ;
        ebss = . ; 
    }

    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.eh_frame)
        *(.comment)
    }

}
```

Kernel Map (for completeness):

```
Discarded input sections

 .comment       0x0000000000000000       0x33 kernelc.o
 .comment       0x0000000000000000       0x33 console.o

Memory Configuration

Name             Origin             Length             Attributes
*default*        0x0000000000000000 0xffffffffffffffff

Linker script and memory map

                0x0000000000010000                . = 0x10000

.text           0x0000000000010000     0x2000
                0x0000000000010000                stext = .
 *(.text)
 .text          0x0000000000010000       0x10 kernelasm.o
 .text          0x0000000000010010       0x14 kernelc.o
                0x0000000000010010                kmain
 .text          0x0000000000010024        0x0 console.o
 *(.rodata)
 *(.rdata)
 *(.rdata$zzz)
                0x0000000000010024                etext = .
                0x0000000000011000                . = ALIGN (ABSOLUTE (.), 0x1000)
 *fill*         0x0000000000010024      0xfdc 
                0x0000000000011000                _sdata = .
                0x0000000000011000                sdata = .
 *(.data)
 .data          0x0000000000011000     0x1000 kernelasm.o
                0x0000000000012000                stack
 .data          0x0000000000012000        0x0 kernelc.o
 .data          0x0000000000012000        0x0 console.o
                0x0000000000012000                _edata = .
                0x0000000000012000                edata = .
                0x0000000000012000                _sbss = .
                0x0000000000012000                sbss = .
 *(COMMON)
 *(.bss)
 .bss           0x0000000000012000        0x0 kernelasm.o
 .bss           0x0000000000012000        0x0 kernelc.o
 .bss           0x0000000000012000        0x0 console.o
                0x0000000000012000                _ebss = .
                0x0000000000012000                ebss = .

.glue_7         0x0000000000012000        0x0
 .glue_7        0x0000000000012000        0x0 linker stubs

.glue_7t        0x0000000000012000        0x0
 .glue_7t       0x0000000000012000        0x0 linker stubs

.vfp11_veneer   0x0000000000012000        0x0
 .vfp11_veneer  0x0000000000012000        0x0 linker stubs

.v4_bx          0x0000000000012000        0x0
 .v4_bx         0x0000000000012000        0x0 linker stubs

.iplt           0x0000000000012000        0x0
 .iplt          0x0000000000012000        0x0 kernelasm.o

.igot.plt       0x0000000000012000        0x0
 .igot.plt      0x0000000000012000        0x0 kernelasm.o

.rel.dyn        0x0000000000012000        0x0
 .rel.iplt      0x0000000000012000        0x0 kernelasm.o

/DISCARD/
 *(.eh_frame)
 *(.comment)
LOAD kernelasm.o
LOAD kernelc.o
LOAD console.o
OUTPUT(kernel.tmp elf32-littlearm)

.ARM.attributes
                0x0000000000000000       0x32
 .ARM.attributes
                0x0000000000000000       0x24 kernelasm.o
 .ARM.attributes
                0x0000000000000024       0x36 kernelc.o
 .ARM.attributes
                0x000000000000005a       0x36 console.o

.note.GNU-stack
                0x0000000000000000        0x0
 .note.GNU-stack
                0x0000000000000000        0x0 kernelc.o
 .note.GNU-stack
                0x0000000000000000        0x0 console.o
```

Kernelasm:

```
ldr sp,=stack
b kmain

forever:
    b forever


.section .data

.global stack
    .rept 1024
    .word 0
    .end
stack:
```

Now, I know in C, I could do something like:

```
#include<graphics.h>
#include<conio.h>

main()
{
   int gd = DETECT, gm;
   initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TC\\BGI");

   setcolor(BLUE); 
   rectangle(50,50,100,100);

   getch();
   closegraph();
   return 0;
}
```

But since I am working with ARM, it complicates matters. As such, I am thinking I need a kernel.

The actual file that does the work:

```
#define blue COLOR16(0,0,255)

void console_init(){

}

void setpixel(x, y, blue){

}
```

The kernel I am using it in:

```
#include "console.h"

void kmain(){

    console_init();
    //draw using setpixel

    while(1){
    }
}
```

I wrote up the skeleton of it, but I am not sure where to go from here. I believe I need to isolate blue from the RBG band and display it, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to go about utilizing the logic I used in the C example for the ARM.

I think I might need to define width and height of the screen for the placement of the rectangle:

```
#define WIDTH 800
#define HEIGHT 600
```

As well as a framebuffer to do the actual communication of where to put the rectangle on the screen:

```
#define framebuffer ((volatile unsigned short*) (((0x07ffffff - WIDTH*HEIGHT*2))&~0xf))
```

And a way to assign the blue to the screen:

```
framebuffer[ HEIGHT/2 * WIDTH + WIDTH/2 ] = #0000FF
```

Could I use something like a script to grab the colors?

```
((b >> 3) | (r << 8) | (g << 3))
```

Any insight would be very helpful in getting the hang of this.

Comment: I would recommend against learning asm by reading gcc compiler output even with optimisation switched off: the gcc does its job in a very good way  and many things it produces in asm code are not obvious for a beginner. First implement everything in C (it does allow to make nearly everything), then after you have working prototype, re-implement in asm  the time-critical parts

Comment: I think you've confused "C" with "a system with an IBM-PC-compatible BIOS and some implementation-specific headers and libraries to interact with it"...

Comment: And to elaborate, in the absence of BIOS code driving the display controller and abstracting it away behind system calls, that means you're writing your own display driver - since you've chosen to emulate an [Integrator CP board](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0159b/ch04s03s06.html), that'll be for [an ARM Ltd. PL110](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0161e/Chdcejdb.html). Perhaps it's also worth noting that this has _precisely_ as much to do with "C translated into ARM instructions" as your PC example does with "C translated into x86 instructions".